# Missing PHP Extension bcmath

Tags: magento2, server-setup

Getting "Missing PHP Extension bcmath"  error while doing Readiness check while doing Magento 2 setup. Even though, I have installed latest PHP bcmath - 7.0

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to install **bcmath.**

1. `sudo apt install php7.1-bcmath` for 7.1 version
2. `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: For me it's working  using this  sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath for 7.2 version

Answer (score 2):

You need to install bcmath extension for resolving this issue, Please try below commands :

**For PHP5.6**

```
sudo apt install php5.6-bcmath
```

**For PHP7.0**

```
sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath
```

**For other** PHP versions

```
sudo apt install php-bcmath
```

After Successfully install you need to restart/reload apache service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that PHP bcmath - 7.0 enable at your system,Create a `phpinfo.php`  at your magento root dir  and write the code `<?php phpinfo();?>` and browse that file  and check  **bcmatch  enabled or not**.

If it  enabled then please goto var folder delete `.setup_cronjob_status` and `.update_cronjob_status` and disabled  all magento cron and try again.

If bcmath is not enable then you should   enable properly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this: as I have not much experience with this.

Comment: I checked - bc2math is enabled. How to disable all magento cron                              Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:
I use PHP version 7.3.33.
Follow this step you won't get an error:

1. **sudo apt install php7.3-bcmath**
2. **sudo service apache2 restart**

Comment: it stills error